# Is there a way to call from sim to app in android

Tags: java, android, mobile-development

I have to make an app which retrieve call from sim to the application which is installed on other user.
for e.g
User A calling from his Sim and User B received that call without containing any sim card on his phone.
Is that possible???

Comment: In general scenario probably not. But if you have some redirection support at the backend, it could be possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be possible if a third party is involved to link both users. This middle man (VoIP server) would need to have a way of receiving calls from the sim and a way of transmitting that to the app.

```
(Sim only) <----> (Sim and App) <----> (App only)
  User A           VoIP Server           User B
```

Think of how you call landlines via Skype for example.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a VoIP solution? As in phone A connected to the internet using mobile data, calling phone B connected to WiFi over a VoIP application